# Linux find command gotcha?

Tags: find

Hi I am trying to find all js & css files in one find command. I tried all of the below but in vain:

```
find WebContent -name "*.[jc]ss?"

find WebContent -name "*.[jc]ss{0,1}"

find WebContent -name "*.[jc][s]{1,2}$"

find WebContent -name "*.[jc]s{1,2}"

find WebContent -name "*.[jc]s[s]?"
```

Now what??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-name` accepts arguments that are [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not regular expressions. You *could* use `-regex` if you wanted to use regular expressions, but the `-o` option (meaning "or") is probably the simplest solution:

```
find WebContent -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css"
```

Comment: thanks to all, I guess I was just trying to dig deep into getting it working using reg exps. I got it working using :
find WebContent -type f \( -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" \)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
find WebContent -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(css|js)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `-iname` option case insensitive

```
find WebContent \( -iname "*.js" -o -iname "*.css" \)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do boolean expressions with find. -o stands for OR.

```
find -name "*.js" -o -name "*.cpp"
```

Comment: -1: you need to either quote or escape those `*` s, e.g. `find -name \\*.js -o -name \\*.cpp` or `find -name "*.js" -o -name "*.cpp"`

Comment: @Omry: it will find matching files in the current directory but not in subdirectories, because the glob is expanded immediately - try it

Comment: @Paul: It also "works" if you have no .js and no .css files in the current directory, because then the glob is expanded to itself.

Comment: Joachim, you just answered a long standing question for me: why unquoted * in bash sometimes works and times not. I suspected it had something to do with files in the current dir but didn't know it expands to itself in such a case (which is a stupid thing to do in my opinion, it should expand to an empty string).

Comment: It's not so much that it expands to itself, as it just doesn't expand at all if nothing is matched - you can see the behaviour by trying something like "rm *.asdf", where it will try to remove the file called "*.asdf".

Comment: @Joachim: good point - that makes two potential failure modes where this may *appear* to work

Comment: @Joachim, @Paul R: If you set the `nullglob` option in bash (using `shopt -s nullglob`), then the glob will be removed if it doesn't match anything.