# shell script or linux command to recursively find all js/css file under public folder

Tags: linux, shell

I need help with shell script or linux command to recursively find all js/css file under public folder, then create the filename.min.jsm on the same directory of previous found but also put the filename.js inside that filename.min.jsm.

For example

```
public/test/a.js
public/b.js
public/test2/test3/c.js
```

output:

```
public/test/a.js
public/test/a.min.jsm  ->  a.js is written inside of this file
public/b.js   
public/b.min.jsm   ->  b.js is written inside of this file
public/test2/test3/c.js
public/test2/test3/c.min.jsm   c.js is written inside of this file
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried and then we can try to suggest any changes or put on some additions.

Comment: @charles babbage  I am new to shell script,  here is something I have tried "find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec echo {} > {}.min.jsm"   and it is not what I expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux find command gotcha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591158/linux-find-command-gotcha)

Comment: @tripleee,  it seems different than what I expect.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your additional requirement until I saw some other answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple refactoring of @choroba's answer which inlines the shell script so you don't need a separate file.

```
find \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' \) -exec sh -c '
    filename=$1
    path=${filename%/*}
    basename=${filename##*/}
    prefix=${basename%%.*}
    echo "$basename" > "$path/$prefix".min.jsm
    ' _ {} \;
```

I added `-o -name '*.css'` and a set of parentheses for grouping the conditions, too. If you don't want to run this on CSS files, revert that change, or add a conditional to the embedded shell script snippet.

Comment: Points to @choroba for the foundation.

Comment: Thanks,  just one thing that you forgot the path.  But I think that's good.  find . \( -name '*.js' -o -name '*.css' \) -exec sh -c '
    filename=$1
    path=${filename%/*}
    basename=${filename##*/}
    prefix=${basename%%.*}
    echo "$basename" > "$path/$prefix".min.jsm
    ' _ {} \;

Comment: The path parameter is optional on Linux; it defaults to the current directory. But certainly, for portability, it is good to include anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
path=${filename%/*}
basename=${filename##*/}
prefix=${basename%%.*}
echo "$basename" > "$path/$prefix".min.jsm
```

Then, run

```
find -name '*.js' -exec /path/to/script.sh {} \;
```

It's not clear what you want to do with the css files, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: is it anyway to make it just command? we kinda don't want to keep any file there.

Comment: @JinLin: So remove it once the files are processed.

Comment: it seems like we can't run js and css at a same time. I try to run "  "find . -name " *.js" -o -name " *.css" -exec /path/to/script.sh {} \;  And it only generate the css one.

Comment: It would be painful to manually create script.sh on each project within different host. running a single command would be ideal.  this is used for the compression later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MY_TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf ${MY_TMPDIR}' EXIT

export fstyle_tmp="${MY_TMPDIR}/fstyle"

find /* -regextype posix-extended -regex '.+\.(js|css)' > "${fstyle_tmp}"

while read line; do

    line2=$(echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/\.js$//' -e 's/\.css$//')
    cp "${line}" "${line2}.min.jsm"

done < "${fstyle_tmp}"

exit 0

#EOF
```

If you dont want copy css content change:

```
line2=$(echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/\.js$//' -e 's/\.css$//')
cp "${line}" "${line2}.min.jsm"
```

For:

```
line2=$(echo "${line}" | sed -e 's/\.js$//' -e 's/\.css$//')

if [[ "${line}" =~ \.js$ ]]; then
   cp "${line}" "${line2}.min.jsm"
else
   touch "${line2}.min.jsm"
fi
```

Comment: @JinLin You can't do it with just a command, they might be more than one result, that means you need to loop it. You can use script and after delete it.